# Missing Elements, Style and other tabs in Safari Web inspector

Tags: macos, safari

I am hoping that someone could help me with this, I've been trying to figure it out why the other tabs are missing. It started after I updated my Safari version to `Version 14.1.1 (15611.2.7.1.6, 15611)`.

OS: Mac Pro MacOs Catalina - 10.15.7 (19H1217)
Browser: Safari Version 14.1.1 (15611.2.7.1.6, 15611)

I wonder if there are settings that need to be configured?

[image]